# Weird looping over bug in nunjucks

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jinja2, nunjucks

I have built a server in nodejs for a multiplayer snake game.

I am currently working on allowing users to create their own bots, and for this I must have a way to generate and store API keys.

I have this figured out. Here is a nice screenshot from AWS DynamoDB showing how the data is formatted.

[image: item schema]

The item we want to focus on is the api_keys row. Expanded, it is just a list of API keys `[<key>,<key>,etc]`
Each api key is just a string that I generate with a helper function.

```js
  function generateAPIKey() {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let apiKey = '';
  
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
      apiKey += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
    }
  
    return apiKey;
  }
```

This all works fine. I then created a login and signup system-> this works fine too!

The problem came up when I tried to make a table of all the API keys for a dashboard. Here is how the dashboard is supposed to look.

[image]

Here is how I managed this one.

```
{% set api_keys =  ["45ZeHLkHLskSbRuBvLObUGZ3lfDSJTVZ","8DAefL5BtSwVOUAp0d1ZYrEEr0sliGBU","9XZLnqBwARSMEFv4O4PBtcxY4Lpob3x2","BKce7wVSnblYEfWv2pAXHlbyrCuPpxmn","BrCv6cHP6uFaohS11GnWIllvzB3VoX4K","CJlyot3evxeR6fgW98sTBblKmrzKaRYy","CsCvTrJrdscXqYoLHnoRBlLwpReNKEJT","IYaitmquR42MafZlpd6clsY9e8NMCcmL","LU06037xiU71ZZJcfgXCauvlTuGybM6N","MZU0aVmyCMcsc2qaVsk9OUXGBixy9zxQ","PapmjncSJYDcUtTaDuatgZwXyIwubiQ2","RH0GV1SqX1IUAL0Rx9MQrlaK3BrK61Mr","RJ3VkuYbp0Zxz2lwQdRGwyKmtpH1JyMY","RMUKYDi0lm0AmQIadaZRx3J6pNWlJ5k9","RvnLoV7vtgEBEhvsLDMVJKXFugcoXHoY","i9LtNKURTBV5R3JGZNnjWfhq0kJz8TgF","ju0ssxnrH3ZoBxhtKwtuFJuWpNAJzSo0","mWBWiIfdA6C3KRCMquGJC76u7WMTPPdE","nyhHKOqT2G2zX95I99MHXKzJLchYsqZb","o0seZ0nYXH021Cy5vTVtthaUqY9whwOp","x5Sj0pFYrK4CDoXAWIrZqhoCTUur3AXo"]  %}
```

This is just filling the `api_keys` variable with randomly generated api keys.

Then, I fill the rows with the following lines

```html
{% for uid in api_keys %}
<tr class = "table-row" id="row-{{ loop.index0 }}">
   <td><b>{{ loop.index0 }}</b></td>
   <td class = "uid">{{ uid }}</td>
   <td class = "manage">
      <button class = "btn btn-inline">Copy Key</button>
      <button class = "btn btn-danger btn-inline">Delete</button>
   </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and this works too!

The problem arises when I try to loop over the user data. If I switch from doing `{% for uid in api_keys %}` to `{% for uid in user.api_keys %}`, everything breaks.

No errors in the console, nothing on the server, but the rows dont print out. I just get an empty table.

I assumed that the error was that user.api_keys was an empty array, or something like that. So, I printed the variable just to check.

```
{{ user.api_keys | dump }}
```

[image]

Logs everything correctly!
The loop just doesnt work when I use the user data instead of template data.

for reference, [here is the full code on github](https://github.com/sojs-coder/MultiSnake-V2/blob/weird-loop-bug/MultiSnake-V2/src/server/views/developers.njk)

If anyone has the foggiest idea please help me out here. Everything looks correct, it just doesnt work!

#### Edit

I have been doing some more testing, and I found that just trying to log 1 element from the list (instead of using dump) returns nothing as well.

```
{{ user.api_keys[0] }}
```

is just empty, while

```
{{ api_keys[0 }} /* the pre filled template one */
```

displays the key properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## After some extensive testing

I have found the bug.

I assumed that dumping the content on the screen provided me with a clear view of what is going on.

After logging the data to the console, you find something very different.

[image]

For those of you struggling to loop over data stored in AWS DynamoDB, notice that the data type is not an array. It is stored in a set.
Access the actual values with `.values`

Not sure if anyone else will have this problem because it's so specific. If any mods think so go ahead and delete the post, or comment that I should.